# why doesn't ArrayList as key in HashMap work?

Tags: java, arraylist, null, hashmap, key

I am trying to use an `ArrayList` as a key in a `HashMap`, but if I add values to the list after setting the list as a key, the map won't recognize the list anymore. I have already found a solution for my problem, but it is an ugly way of doing it, here is some example code for the problem:

```
HashMap<Object,String> hm = new HashMap<Object,String>();

List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
hm.put(l, "stuff");
l.add("test");//add item after adding the list to the hashmap

System.out.println(hm.get(l));
```

this will return the text "null" while

```
HashMap<Object,String> hm = new HashMap<Object,String>();

List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("test"); //add item before adding the list to the hashmap
hm.put(l, "stuff");

System.out.println(hm.get(l));
```

works fine and returns "stuff"

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: How well do you understand hashing?

Comment: Short answer: Changing the ArrayList changes its content identity. It is illegal to change the identity of an object when it is the key of an entry in a HashMap. So you must remove the list, perform the changes, then put it back into the HashMap.

Comment: Adding something to the `ArrayList` changes its `hashcode`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils not well, I basicaly understand how to work with java, but don't understand how any of it works pretty much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short: because keys must be immutable for hashmaps to work (at least their identity must be immutable) and lists aren't.

Long: when you add a key to a map its `hashCode()` method is used to determine the bucket the entry is put into. Inside that bucket `equals()` is used to check whether that key already exists in there. The same is true for lookups.

Now `ArrayList` does a deep `equals()` and `hashCode()` so if you alter the list *after* using it as key you'll end up in a different bucket or with a different outcome for `equals()` and the map most likely won't find it.

**Edit**

`hashCode()` implementation for `AbstractList` (which `ArrayList` extends):

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

As you can see: if the list is empty the hash code will be 1 otherwise the hash code will be something else (in your case `31 * "test".hashCode()`). Thus you're likely to end up looking in a different bucket which will fail.

**Edit 2**

Clarification on "different outcome for `equals()`": of course `equals()` should return true if the list used as a key and the list used for the lookup *only* contain equal elements in the same order. But if you change that list after using it as a key you might end up in different situations:

- Although hashCode returns a different value it might get mapped to the same bucket (in the worst case think of only one bucket in the map). In that case you'd end up with two equal keys in the list although they weren't equal before.
- You might not be aware of changes to the list and thus might not use an equal list for the lookup even if you think you are.

Comment: The list will always be equal to itself. But its hashCode changes.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, it will always equal to itself or other lists with equal elements in the same order. What I was getting at is: if you change the list later on you're also changing what `equals()` operates on and thus you might end up checking for different keys or even have equal keys in the same bucket (rare but possible). In essence: don't use keys that change their identity :)

Comment: Thanks for the explenation, I would asume the same applies to hashmaps themselves right? Where the hash will change when modifying the hashmap?

Comment: @thegunmaster yes that basically applies to any mutable collection (that is most maps, lists, sets etc.)