# JAVA - Storing result set in hash table by grouping data efficiently

Tags: java, mysql, hashtable

I'd like to store in a hash table a result set coming from a query execution.
The hash table is something like this

```
Map<List<String>,List<Object>>
```

where

```
List<String>, the hash table key, is a subset of the extracted fields
Object is a Java object corresponding to a database tuple (all fields)
```

So, first, data have to be grouped in order to create each key and group all the items sharing this key.

The pseudo-code related to my current approach is:

```
while(iterate){
     while(rs.next){ 
          if(key is empty)
                // build REFERENCE KEY and delete rs entry
          else
                // build key for i-th rs entry and compare it with the REFERENCE key. 
                   Eventually, get data and delete rs entry
     }
     rs.beforeFirst()
}
```

In other words, the result set is iterated many times and each time a new key is created, in order to compare the ramaining result set entries with it. Each time the processed entry is deleted to exit the outer loop.

Since the result set is very large (and also each List(Object) ), performance are poor (a very high loading time per key).
Appending an **order by** clause to the query (in order to preliminarily group data) doesn't alleviate the problem.

Is there a more efficient approach?

Thanks everyone.

EDIT

```
Input ResultSet
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | Field5 | Field6 | Field7 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    X   |    A   | val1_3 | val1_4 | val1_5 | val1_6 | val1_7 |
|    X   |    A   | val2_3 | val2_4 | val2_5 | val2_6 | val2_7 |
|    Y   |    B   | val3_3 | val3_4 | val3_5 | val3_6 | val3_7 |
|    Z   |    C   | val4_3 | val4_4 | val4_5 | val4_6 | val4_7 |
|    Y   |    D   | val5_3 | val5_4 | val5_5 | val5_6 | val5_7 |
----------------------------------------------------------------

Key_Fields : [Field1, Field2]

Output Map
----------------------------------- 
|   KEY  |     VALUE              |  
-----------------------------------
| [X,A]  |   [Object1, Object2]   |
| [Y,B]  |   [Object3]            |
| [Z,C]  |   [Object4]            |
| [Y,D]  |   [Object5]            |
-----------------------------------
```

I'm using `List<String>` for key because another `ResultSet` can have a `Key_Fields` of different lenght.

Here, my current time-consuming Java code

```
while(itera){

            key = new ArrayList<String>();
            values = new ArrayList<AbstractClass>();

            while(rs.next()){

                if(key.isEmpty()){
                     // build REFERENCE KEY
                     // add first OBJECT to List<AbstractClass>
                     // delete this data from ResultSet
                }
                else{
                    // Build KEY_TO_BE_COMPARED
                    List<String> row_to_be_compared = new ArrayList<String>();
                   // If this key equals to REFERENCE KEY       
                    if(row_to_be_compared.equals(key)){
                        AbstractClass value_object = new AbstractClass();
                        ...
                        rs.deleteRow();
                    }
                    // ORDERBY clause in query ensures that, if keys don't match, then all objects related to REFERENCE KEY have been collected
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            rs.beforeFirst();

            map.put(key, values);

            if(!rs.next() || items_loaded==max_hash_size)
                itera = false;
            else
                rs.beforeFirst();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using list as key? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560067/why-doesnt-arraylist-as-key-in-hashmap-work

Comment: @Ashutosh Do you think using `String` rather than `List<String>` can reduce the execution time?

Comment: The thing is you cannot use List<String> as key, leave aside execution time. Key has to be immutable.

Comment: Ok. Since `String` is immutable, it is an alternative. Thanks for your tip. Regarding the initial question, any idea?

Comment: I don't completely get your question. If you can show some sample values and final output then i will be able to reply. If possible paste your exact working code.

Comment: To answer your initial question, I'm using List<String> because the Map has different types of key, whose lenght can vary.

Comment: What do you mean by different types of keys, it will be fixed, i mean if you initialize Map<String, List<Object>> it will always have String as key. String can handle lengthy keys as well as short keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125589/discussion-between-fab-and-ashutosh-jha).

Comment: Can you paste your code of how you are building reference key and how you are deleting? I mean don't skip any line code, as that will help me in thinking about how to optimise operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using List as key. Use a class having List as its instance variable. Override equals very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simplify your key and make it a String that contains all the concatenated fields concatenated by a special character (say `.`)?